# What does $\mathbb{R}^ {\times}$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does $\mathbb{R}^ {\times}$ mean? I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: The multiplicative group of the reals (so $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ under multiplication).

Comment: I have seen this notation for the set of elements having a multiplicative inverse. For the real numbers, these are all except $0$, so my guess is all real numbers, zero excluded.

Comment: Interestingly $\mathbb R^+$ does not stand for the additive group of reals.

Answer (score 1):

It is the set of the inversible elements of $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a ring. It is then  $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.